# NetBeans/Java - breakpoint can't catch exception

Tags: java

In NetBeans / Java - exception breakpoint (for Throwable) does not catch exceptions (RuntimeException in code of library for servlet). If you search tediously, you can find a purple stop line but without looking into the state of variables, etc. VS.NET does not have such ailments - it stops where you need it and everything is clear.

Is this a NetBeans problem or Java? How to get rid of breakpoint problems?

Comment: So other breakpoints work? Then it might be a misplacement of the breakpoint location. Removing the breakpoint and readding it, maybe on several lines, could help. The IDE is guilty.

Comment: You need to add more context. There are many versions of NetBeans and Java (JDK), there are multiple types of breakpoints in NetBeans, the exact way that you launched the servlet is very relevant (as well as the exact servlet container that is managing it) and so on. As it is, your question is way too generic to answer.

Answer (score 0):

**In here example would give you basic understanding of Exception Handling in Servlet**

Actually putting a break point you can not catch a servlet exception because of it is happening before reaching the end point then you have to do something like this

When a servlet generates an error developers can handle those exceptions in various ways

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet("/SampleExceptionHandler")
public class SampleExceptionHandler extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        exceptionProcessor(request, response);
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        exceptionProcessor(request, response);
    }

    private void exceptionProcessor(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        // Analyze the servlet exception
        Throwable throwable = (Throwable) request
                .getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.exception");
        Integer statusCode = (Integer) request
                .getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.status_code");
        String servletName = (String) request
                .getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.servlet_name");
        if (servletName == null) {
            servletName = "Unknown";
        }
        String requestUri = (String) request
                .getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.request_uri");
        if (requestUri == null) {
            requestUri = "Unknown";
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: I'll have to find my own. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Okay However thank dear . for your reply ,Have a Good day